# Global variable as an argument of function call in C

Tags: c, global-variables

While passing global variable in function parameter, is it passed as reference or value?

For example:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int global_var = 5;

int foo(int p) { // p for parameter
    return p * 10;
}

int main() {
    return foo(global_var);
}
```

Comment: check my answer I hope you will find that useful

Comment: I tested, it is showing Pass by value.

Comment: if you such things it will already create a local variable first of all give your code link I will show you how.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is passed by value. The following code shows that this is the case:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int global = 5;

void foo(int bar){
    bar = 6;
    printf("bar = %d\nglobal = %d", bar, global);
}

int main(){
    foo(global);
    return 0;
}
```

The output is:

> bar = 6
>
> global = 5

In this code `global` was passed as a parameter for `foo`, we called this parameter `bar`. So at the beginning `global` and `bar` are two different variables both having the value 5. But then `bar` is assigned the value 6 and since the argument was referenced by value, `global` stays at 5.

To pass the variable by reference, use pointers:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int global = 5;

void foo(int *bar){
    *bar = 6;
    printf("bar = %d\nglobal = %d", *bar, global);
}

int main(){
    foo(&global);
    return 0;
}
```

Now the output is:

> bar = 6
>
> global = 6

Comment: Thanks. That's what I actually wanted.

Answer (score 3):

Both local and global variables are passed to functions by value in C. If you need to pass by reference, you will need to use pointers.

Answer (score 3):

How the variable is/must be passed, depends on the function, not on the variable:

```
int gMyVar;

void foo(int a);        // says "call me by value"
void bar(int *b);       // says "call my by reference"
```

`foo` requires an int to be passed. you must call it as `foo(gMyVar`).

`bar` requires a pointer to an int. You must call it as `bar(&gMyVar)`.

So, as other answers indicated, C always passes a value, however, the value can be the value of a variable (call by value) or can be a pointer to a variable (call by reference).

Answer (score 1):

First of all, Why do we need to pass Global variable in a function? we can directly access it any where in the program if you dont know.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int x = 10;  //global variable

void fun()
{

 printf("%d",x);    // direct access
}
int main(void) {

    fun();     // no argument required
    return 0;
}
```

Output

```
10
```

For demo http://ideone.com/VLWqNO

Comment: Thanks for your help. :)

Comment: I don't have such repo yet to vote you. :)

Comment: @user367180 it's your post you can upvote an answer or accept an answer is that fine? yes you can accept only one answer with green tick :)